# Issue converting array_diff_uassoc to static method with splat operator

Tags: php

There is a function in PHP called `array_diff_uassoc`.

According to the PHP Api, its function parameters are:

```
array_diff_uassoc ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ], callable $key_compare_func )
```

I'm trying to convert it to a static method:

```
public static function arrayDiffUassoc(array $array1,array $array2,...$arrays,callable $keyCompareFunc):array
{
    return array_diff_uassoc($array1,$array2,...$arrays,$keyCompareFunc);
}
```

The issue is I cannot explicity use the splat operator for the 3rd parameter as it apparently must be the last argument.

How can i implement this function as a static method with adhering to the splat operator as well as the last argument being the callable function?

**I'm trying to implement this the same way as the PHP Api**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately variadics have to be specified as the last argument in a function declaration. Otherwise they don't work.

You can accomplish what you're trying to do by relying on old school `func_get_args`, followed by a `call_user_func_array`

See Variadics: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

See `func_get_args`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

See `call_user_func_array`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: Can you assist in a simple implementation?